# Phonegap create project error - "module not found"

Tags: node.js, cordova, cmd, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have installed node.js(node-v4.2.3-x64) in my windows system. I followed the exact tutorial on getting started in phonegap website. The nodejs installed successfully and when I create new project using `phonegap create my-app`, It shows module not found error. I have attached screenshot for reference. Kindly help me..

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `npm install` first, and then run `phonegap create my-app`.

You don't need to do `npm install` everytime you create a new one, just the first time because that installs any and all the packages that nodejs requires but can't find.

Also if that does not work try doing `npm install cordova -g` and `npm install phonegap -g`.